# Flutter: Change Bottom Navigation Bar Items on real time

Tags: flutter

I am trying to see how I can change the items in BottomNavigationBar within a DefaultTabController on real time but came to no avail.

Basically these are the scenario:

1. Non-admin Tab Bar: [Screen A and B]
2. Admin Tab Bar: [Screen C, D and B]

Within screen B, there is a button to change from Admin to non-admin view or vice versa.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works. But, I would advise using a Provider rather than passing a WidgetState as an argument to any function or to any Widget.

```dart
List<Widget> nonAdminWidgets(_BottomNavScaffoldState parent) {
  return <Widget>[
    ProfilePage(parent),
    ClothesPage(),
    ColorsPage(),
  ];
}

List<Widget> adminWidgets(_BottomNavScaffoldState parent) {
  return <Widget>[
    ProfilePage(parent),
    IdeasPage(),
  ];
}

int _currentIndex = 0;

bool isAdmin = true;

List<dynamic> nonAdminNavBars = [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    title: Text('Profile'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.face_rounded),
  ),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    title: Text('Clothes'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.design_services_rounded),
  ),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    title: Text('Colors'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.colorize_rounded),
  ),
];

List<dynamic> adminNavBars = [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    title: Text('Profile'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.face_rounded),
  ),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    title: Text('Ideas'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline_rounded),
  ),
];

class BottomNavScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavScaffoldState createState() => _BottomNavScaffoldState();
}

class _BottomNavScaffoldState extends State<BottomNavScaffold> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: isAdmin ? adminWidgets(this)[_currentIndex] : nonAdminWidgets(this)[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        onTap: (value) {
          _currentIndex = value;
          setState(() {});
        },
        items: isAdmin ? adminNavBars : nonAdminNavBars,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClothesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          "Clothes",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          "Colors",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IdeasPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          "Ideas",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  _BottomNavScaffoldState parent;

  ProfilePage(this.parent);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        isAdmin = !isAdmin;
        _currentIndex = 0;
        parent.setState(() {});
      },
      child: Text("Change"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Preet, I will take a look and get back asap.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote this because I am new and do not have enough reputation.

Comment: You don't have to upvote it. You need to mark it as accepted. Happy to help. :)